# I'm trying to use my other domain

Tags: http, xampp, vhosts

I just got a new domain and i'm trying to use it for a different site but I can't get it to work. It still sends me to my other domain name instead. I try to look it up how to do it but I can't find away to do it, What should I do?? Here is the code,

```
ServerName dstokesncstudio.org


<VirtualHost 69.132.203.191:80>
 ServerName dstokesncstudio.org:80
 ServerAlias www.dstokesncstudio.org
 DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio"
 DirectoryIndex index.html

 TransferLog "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio/logs/access.log" 
 ErrorLog "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio/logs/error.log"

 <Directory "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio">
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>


 </VirtualHost>


ServerName dejesusconstruction.com
<VirtualHost 69.132.203.191:8080>
ServerName www.dejesusconstruction.com:8080
ServerAlias www.dejesusconstruction.com
DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio/jesus"
DirectoryIndex index.html


<Directory "C:/htdocs/www/dstokesncstudio/jesus">
DirectoryIndex index.html
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>



 <VirtualHost 69.132.203.191:80>
 ServerName dstokesncstudio.org

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 69.132.203.191:8080>
ServerName dejesusconstruction.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

As

> http://ping.eu/nslookup/

say

```
dstokesncstudio.org     => 216.239.38.21,216.239.32.21,...
dejesusconstruction.com => 216.239.38.21,216.239.32.21,...
```

not `69.132.203.191`

I think you want name based virtual hosts https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

In your case remove the `ServerName ...` outside of the `VirtualHost ...` and add on top

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

If you also want to reach the second domain also on port 80 then you dont't need the second line.

Now remove the IP from the `VirtualHost` as the link above have described and voila you should reach the domains.

Comment: Thanks @Aleks I tried that at first and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Now its saying Access forbidden

Comment: its still going to my other domain still but when I go to it on a mobile phone its says / not on this server.

Comment: I got this body as answer from this url **http://www.dejesusconstruction.com/** **hbh**. tested with http://onlinecurl.com/ . The response from **http://www.dstokesncstudio.org/** is a html site witch some javascript. Are this the expected responses? you could try to execute `ipconfig /flushdns`